# Is there any way of creating facebook events using Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to build an app for publicising events. Ideally I would like to create the event via my app and somehow add this as an event to a business facebook page. Every avenue I have looked at suggests that what I want to do is just not possible.

Am I correct in this conclusion?

As a workaround, can you use the facebook API to create timed posts such that they would appear on a businesses time line with date and time on?

Comment: Correct, there is no way to create events via API for normal 3rd-party apps.

Comment: You can make page feed posts with a `scheduled_publish_time`, but those posts will of course not offer any of the “features” events do.